# How jQuery custom event namespaces work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Having two listeners with the namespaces `one.two.three` and `one.half.two.three`. When triggering `one.two.three` triggers `one.half.two.three` to. Why?

```js
$(document).on('one.two.three', function(e){
    console.log('1st event');
});

$(document).on('one.half.two.three', function(e){
    console.log('2nd event');
});

$(document).trigger('one.two.three');

// logs '1st event' and '2st event'
```

Comment: [jquery custom events naming conventions](//stackoverflow.com/q/7366167)